# Pyqt5 Multiple Windows - How to prevent window switching?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making a GUI using pyqt5 and I have two windows. In the first window, there is a button to open the second window. Now, I want to prevent windows switching from the second window to the first one. For example, when we open file dialog, we cannot switch to the main window and the main window is not clickable. (you can check it)

I have tried to set windows flag with :

```
setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

but it just makes the second window stay on top and I can still switch to the first window. Is there a way to prevent windows switching or make the first window to be not clickable?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the window modal by:

```
setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
```

Comment: It is what I want! Thank you